# how to create Dyamic React responsive carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jquery-ui-slider

I Have been working in dynamic Image and Video Gallery in React JS. I Want to implement the Carusoal to view the image and video in slider concept.

Comment: Demo Link http://leandrowd.github.io/react-responsive-carousel/

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having? Why does the example not work for you?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h-KgA2OcXf5w3841ToKTP9UcbeX8xfH0PHzZssMr1r4/edit?usp=sharing  Here I Shared the link  @JacobSmit

Comment: I Want to implement the Carusoal to view the image and video in slider concept, couldn't implement next slider

Answer (score 0):

Installing as a package

```
yarn add react-responsive-carousel
```

Usage

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; // requires a loader
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';

class DemoCarousel extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Carousel>
                <div>
                    <img src="assets/1.jpeg" />
                    <p className="legend">Legend 1</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="assets/2.jpeg" />
                    <p className="legend">Legend 2</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="assets/3.jpeg" />
                    <p className="legend">Legend 3</p>
                </div>
            </Carousel>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<DemoCarousel />, document.querySelector('.demo-carousel'));

// Don't forget to include the css in your page

// Using webpack or parcel with a style loader
// import styles from 'react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css';

// Using html tag:
// <link rel="stylesheet" href="<NODE_MODULES_FOLDER>/react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"/>
```

Refrence: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel

Comment: Hi @Makwana Prahlad, It's a static value, I have dynamic